# change layout of code-block in pptx generated with md and pandoc

Tags: markdown, powerpoint, pandoc

I'm using pandoc to convert markdown into powerpoint. I have a reference-doc .pptx file that defines headers, text, enumerations, and so on.

However, I would also like to **format code blocks** differently.

a sample of my md file:

````
% PySpark 

---

# demo

the following is a codeblock
```
spark = SparkSession 
  .builder() 
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example") 
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") 
```

and this is `iline code`

---

# next slide
````

[compiled pptx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv3Vi.png)

I would like the code-block to have **less spacing** between lines, use a slightly **smaller font** and have a **darker box around it**, to improve readability. (And to make more code fit on one slide)

The inline code is ok, though it is sometimes hard to discern from the text. if there are improvements possible I'd make them, too.

I use the following command to produce the pptx file:

```
pandoc slides.md 
        -o /Users/.../Output/slides.pptx \
        --reference-doc /Users/.../Reference/tecRacerNew.pptx
```

I tried to change the font at least, but even that proves difficult:
`--variable monospace="PT Mono"`.

```
---
title: pyspark
monospace: PT Mopno
---
```

both won't work. And they don't solve the problem of line spacing or fontsize.

is there any way to define code-block layout inside the reference doc? or inside the md or with the pandoc command?

I found the following posts, hinting it must be possible, but I just can't figure out how...
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4999
https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-powerpoint
https://pandoc.org/releases.html release 2.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using pandoc version 2.18 and have a metadata section that looks like this

```
---
title: Why Python?
monofont: Iosevka Fixed SS01
---
```

This works for me when creating .pptx files. Both code snippets and monospace text have the font specified.